# How can I merge one dataframe into another, inserting rows that do not exist?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with an eyetracker that samples at 500 hz, thus I have a measurement every 2ms.  I've loaded this data into a dataframe and reindexed it with the time samples, such that my row indexes match the time, in ms, where the recording was made:

Here's a slice of this dataframe (note that the `event` column contains empty strings right now):

```
           x       y      cr event
2000   109.9  1133.7  4264.0      
2001   109.0  1133.3  4267.0      
2002   107.1  1130.6  4269.0      
2003   104.3  1128.0  4270.0      
2004    97.8  1125.2  4268.0      
2005    89.8  1124.3  4266.0      
2006    79.2  1121.3  4274.0      
2007    69.5  1118.7  4284.0      
2008    59.6  1116.7  4293.0      
2009    53.0  1116.9  4291.0      
2010    48.6  1117.1  4290.0
```

As you can see, there are no odd-numbered time indexes, again, because the machine samples every 2 ms.

My second DataFrame tracks TTLs that are sent to the eyetracker.  These TTLs can occur at any time with millisecond resolution, so there *can* be odd-numbered timestamps, here.  This second DataFrame has two columns, `t` and `msg`.  Here's a slice:

```
     t           msg
0    11911  WarningOnset
1    12510      CueOnset
2    14693  WarningOnset
3    17009  WarningOnset
4    17642      CueOnset
```

My goal is to merge the second dataframe into the first, such that each item in the `msg` column of dataframe2 gets placed into the `event` column of dataframe1 at the index indicated by column `t`.

This means that some of the indexes I'm targeting in dataframe1 do not yet exist, which is why my current approach is failing with a `KeyError`.

Here's what I tried:

```
samples.loc[events['t'], 'event'] = events['msg']  # throws KeyError
```

What is the correct way of doing this?  For clarity, I'd like to either place `NaN`s in the columns that did not exist in dataframe2 (i.e. `events` in the example above).

Comment: Did you look at the `join` method?

Comment: @BrenBarn, I'm looking now, thanks! (An example would still be welcome, if at all possible)

Comment: Have you tried `df.merge(df1, on='t', how='left')`, assuming df is your first dataframe and df1 is your second

Comment: @EdChum, Yikes, looks like I made a small mistake in my example (it's fixed now).  There is no `t` column in the first dataframe, so I would need to merge onto the index, it seems.  I'll give it a whirl.  For clarity, the `t` column in the second dataframe corresponds to the index values in the first.

Comment: @blz your first df seems to have year as it's index it isn't clear how t relates to the first df's index, you need either indexes that mean the same thing or a common column in both df's in order to merge them in any meaningful way

Comment: @EdChum, they're miliseconds, not years.  I just took an arbitrary slice for illustrative purposes.  Again, this is the same kind of data as in df2's `t` column.  I need to use the `t` column from df2 to identify the proper row in df1 -- is that clearer?

My attempt with `samples.loc` illustrates what I'm trying to do.  The only problem is that it seems unwilling to insert rows that do not already exist.

Comment: @blz in which case what you do is `df1.set_index(['t'],inplace=True)` and then merge: `df=df.merge(df1, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')`

Comment: You can also use `combine_first`: `df.combine_first(df1)`

Comment: @EdChum, ok we're definitely getting there! =)  This gives me a dataframe with all the elements in the proper place, but in a seperate `msg` column.  I'd like for the `msg` column from the second dataframe to become the `event` column on the first.  This can be done simply by `df['event'] = d['msg']` followed by `df.drop('msg', axis=1, inplace=True)`.  Is there a way to do all of this in one line?  **Edit:** either way, I'll be happy to accept `combine_first` as an answer if you want to write it up!

Comment: @blz just rename the column before merging `df1.rename(columns={'msg':'event'})`, or you can just do it after merge by dropping the column from df: `df.drop('event', axis=1)` then rename msg to event: `df.rename({'msg':'event'})`

Comment: @EdChum,  I'm getting an unrelated error now, so I think it's best if I clean everything up and ask in a separate question.  Thanks very much for your help in the meantime!

Comment: @blz I will post what I have commented already so that there is an actual answer to your principal problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your initial attempt fails is that the values don't exist in your target dataframe, what you want to do is assign events where there is a match and set events to NaN or blank or whatever where there are no real events.

What you want to do is merge the other df to your first one on either an index (which should represent the same thing) or columns which should represent the same thing.

You will also need to rename your column in the second df.

So rename the column:

```
df1.rename({'msg':'event'})
```

Now set column 't' to be your index

```
df1.set_index(['t'],inplace=True)
```

Now merge:

```
df.merge(df1, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')
```

You can also use combine first which preserves the left hand side dataframes data:

```
df.combine_first(df1)
```